# Dynamic subdivision

Tags: edit-mode, subdivision-surface

Is there an option on Blender 2.83 to apply dynamic subdivision like in ZBrush?

Click [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/img0.recordit.co/b9uTLtFD0m.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAUQ5RURZ7ND2T2B6I&Expires=1598208801&Signature=Dj91Xe3E4JnXU5bQk1dYSbhj2X0%3D) to see what I'm talking about

Comment: Hello :). Please add more information into the body of your question, instead of using a link. Links can expire or get broken.

Comment: Btw, the link IS broken: *"This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. "*

Comment: Hi. Please use the built-in uploader when adding images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post . Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to get 'dynamic subdivision'. I'm not entirely sure what you are going for. The 1. Method is a Multiresolution Modifier. It allows you to switch between different levels of subdivision during sculpting.
The 2. Option is Dyntopo, it will triangluate your mesh and add geometry wherever you're scultping, depending on the division level you chose and the brush size. 
the 2. Option is distructive, it will replace your mesh and UVs, while the 1. option is not.

Let me know if one of these methods is what you are looking for and I can attach screenshots, if you are having trouble with the options.

Comment: You can also get "dynamic" subdivision by enabling the "Experimental" feature set, adding a subdiv modifier and set it to "adaptive"

Comment: That would be in render though, I think he wants to sculpt with dynamic subdivisions